# Fullcalendar not posting valid JSON

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I just can't figure out what's wrong with this code, I have all dependencies loaded jquery 1.9.1 jquery UI 1.10.2, fullcalendar.min.js and am following the example just as it's shown.

Here is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mypage.cfc',              
                data: JSON.stringify({ param_one: "test", param_two: "testing"}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function() {
                    //alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            }
        });

    });
```

On the coldfusion back end page, that is expecting JSON, I kept getting JSON parsing failure, so I checked firebug to see what is being sent in the POST and it's not sending a valid JSON data. Here is what firebug shows in the POST:

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=p&3=a&4=r&5=a&6=m&7=_&8=o&9=n&10=e&11=%22&12=%3A&13=%22&14=t&15=e&16=s&17=t&18=%22&19=%2C&20=%22&21=p&22=a&23=r&24=a&25=m&26=_&27=t&28=w&29=o&30=%22&31=%3A&32=%22&33=t&34=e&35=s&36=t&37=i&38=n&39=g&40=%22&41=%7D&start=1361685600&end=1365310800
```

I've also tried trimming the code completely down, to see if I can narrow the problem down, so I just tired:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: 'mypage.cfc'
        });

    });
```

And in this case nothing get's posted at all. I see in the params tab this:

```
_   1364228830548
end 1365310800
format  json
start   1361685600
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to stringify? Doesn't `data: { param_one: "test", param_two: "testing"}` work?

Comment: @ganeshk I tried w/o stringify first, and it also wasn't posting valid JSON. W/O stringify the post looks like this: param_one=test&param_two=testing&start=1361685600&end=1365310800

Comment: which is correct, right? Isn't your coldfusion backend able to process that? The issue might be that FullCalendar never sends anything in JSON format - it is "expecting" results in JSON though.

Comment: @ganeshk Thanks you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Ok I hope this helps someone else struggling with this. Thanks to ganeshk for pointing me in the right direction. The documentation for fullcalendar is sparse, I thought the jquery code was supposed to send JSON data, but it doesn't. It just sends a string.

On the coldfusion side if you want to capture the string you can use something like this:

```
        <!--- query string --->
        <cfset URLstring = getHTTPRequestData().content >

        <!--- local structure --->
        <cfset cfData = StructNew()>
        <!--- loop our query string values and set them in our structure --->
        <cfloop list="#URLstring#" index="key" delimiters="&">
            <cfset cfData["#listFirst(key,'=')#"] = urlDecode(listLast(key,"="))>
        </cfloop>
```

Then in your code in your SQL WHERE statment you can use #cfData["start"]# or any other params that you pass.

Once you have your query, you can populate an array and send it back and it will populate the calendar.